# How to export EE1 entries and comments and re-import them to another EE1 install?

Tags: ee1, import, export

Is there an add-on that makes this fairly easy to accomplish? We'd only like to export/import blog entries and the field groups are identical on both EE installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using the following EE 1.x compatible addons.

[Import Data Into ExpressionEngine](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/import-data-into-expressionengine)

[CSV Grab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/csvgrab)

[Feed Grab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feedgrab)

The third option is probably the easiest as all you'd need to do is set up an RSS feed in your existing site and then point to it on your new site following the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Sean! I wasn't aware of those and they didn't turn up in my search.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any addon out there for such a purpose and I'm not sure I'd trust it entirely if there was in comparison to grabbing the data from the database directly.

I can't remember the EE1 DB schema but they should be fairly easy to get to. In EE2 all your channel data is listed in `exp_channel_*` and comments in `exp_comments`. Possibly also `exp_comment_subscriptions` if there are any. It should follow a similar suit in EE1 so you can export the data from those tables and import into your new database. Just double check if you have any addons in use which may link into channel entries and be sure to install those wherever it's being moved to and grab their data too.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I thought about doing this but not sure if I'm confident that won't cause any problems in the future. There's not a WHOLE lot of entries to be migrated, so I'm thinking it may be best to let the client do it manually. We use disqus for comments so there's only entry data, thankfully.

Comment: The best thing would be to give it a test on a sandbox site/database first to ensure all the data is brought across. You'll need to make sure any users/user groups and permissions are matched if you have different users making posts but if it's EE1 to EE2 then it shouldn't be too tricky.